# ref in Nuxt 3, how to loop the all ref in html

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have some code work in Nuxt2

```
for (let i = 0; i < couponLength; i++) {
    let childComponent = this.$refs[`inputValue${i}`];
    let message = childComponent.checkRequired();
    if (message.result == false) {
        this.error_message.push(message.message);
    }
}
```

However, I need to change to Nuxt 3 and there is no $this in Nuxt 3 and Nuxt 3's ref needs to name it as ref in HTML to connect it. I cannot use `inputValue${i}` to create a ref(), What can I do? That ref is components.

```
const first_name_ref = ref(null);
const last_name_ref = ref(null);
const area_code_ref = ref(null);
const phone_number_ref = ref(null);
const inputValue5 = ref(null);
const inputValue6 = ref(null);
onMounted(() => {
    refArr.value.push(first_name_ref.value);
    refArr.value.push(last_name_ref.value);
    refArr.value.push(area_code_ref.value);
    refArr.value.push(phone_number_ref.value);
    refArr.value.push(inputValue5.value);
    refArr.value.push(inputValue6.value);
})
```

This code works but every time I add a new input, I need to change the code to add a new ref()

Comment: new method change to another name since I don't use numbers to loop the ref. You can change any name.

Comment: Please share the html

Comment: Use "Updated" hook!

Comment: @ShafranAshraff Updated hook runs every time the component rerenders, what purpose would it serve here?  I will just add that the original code needs more clarification.  what is the expected result of ``this.$refs[`inputValue${i}`]`` when `i` is 0?  you only have inputs for `i` values of 5 and 6.  Are you meaning to loop _all_ refs, or just the inputValue refs?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `onMounted` to get all your template refs

```js
onMounted(() => {
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(getCurrentInstance().refs)) {
    // Todo
  }
})
```

You will get an object that look like the old `this.$refs`